# How to find and delete a file with CMD command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I know the filename, say `myfile.pdf`. But I do not know its location because my web application created it temporarily. When the user disconnect from the application then I want this file to be deleted. So how to search and delete the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
del path\filename /s
```

e.g.

```
del c:\test\h.bat /s
```

Will delete h.bat in any sub folders from the test directory.

To search and delete on an entire drive: -

```
del c:\test.bat /s
```

The S switch deletes all specified files from all subdirectories.

Comment: is it related to the current directory ? Because I do not know the location of the file !

Answer (score 0):

You can ***delete*** files by using this command.

- rm [filename]